# Analog for :t from ghci

Tags: haskell

Reading haskell book about [types](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#believe-the-type) I want to repeat sample for `:t` command:

```
ghci> :t 'a'  
'a' :: Char  
ghci> :t True  
True :: Bool  
ghci> :t "HELLO!"  
"HELLO!" :: [Char]  
ghci> :t (True, 'a')  
(True, 'a') :: (Bool, Char)  
ghci> :t 4 == 5  
4 == 5 :: Bool
```

Unfortunately I can't install haskell locally, thatswhy I use ideone.com

But I can't understand how create the same sample.

I tried like this:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Start"
    :t 'a'
    putStrLn "Finish"
```

or this:

```
:t 'a'
```

or:

```
putStrLn ("Finish" ++ show :t 'a')
```

Is there a possibility to show types without installing ghci? Maybe, there is another web fiddle that can do this?

Comment: You can use [**`typeOf`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf) to obtain the `TypeRep` object. It requires that your type is `Typeable`, but with the given examples that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`typeOf :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> TypeRep`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf) to obtain the `TypeRep` object. It requires that your type is `Typeable`, but with the given examples that is the case.

For example:

```
import Data.Typeable(typeOf)

main = putStrLn ("Finish" ++ show (typeOf 'a'))
```

This will not print full polymorphic types, since at compile time the types are determined. You thus see the type as is derived by the Haskell compiler.

Comment: Thanks, it works at ideone.com! I'll accept you answer after 9 minutes.

Comment: Can we use function names with typeOf? `main = putStrLn ("Finish" ++ show (typeOf head))` doesn't works. Are functions `Typeable` or not?

Comment: @AK: no, it will simply convert a expression with a type to the `TypeRep` of that expression. The information of the expression is "gone". The type can also be determined at *compile time* (since Haskell has full type erasure).

Comment: Perhaps you should add a note explaining that in this way you can't print the full polymorphic type which GHCi shows.

Comment: As mentioned [in comments](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1306353/213987) on Stackoverflow In Russian there's an website with ghci console: https://replit.com

Comment: @AK You can use `typeOf` with functions, but you must supply enough information to the compiler for it to know what type the function has! As Willem says, `typeOf` only understands monomorphic types, so polymorphic types must be specialized. The compiler refuses to specialize unless it knows from context what type the variables must be instantiated to. Practically speaking, this means `typeOf` isn't useful for *discovering* types of many things, not just functions (try `typeOf Proxy`), since you sort of need to already know the type to know how to provide the right specialization information.